# Can startActivityForResult() send data?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, start-activity

I am learning android and curious to know as if `startActivityForResult()` contains the properties of `startActivity()` too, i.e. can it be used to send data like `startActivity()` beside receiving data from called activity?

Here is the code:
SendData Activity:

```
Intent data= new Intent(SendData.this, RecieveData.class);
Bundle check = new Bundle();

check.putString("UmerData", cheese);
medt.setText(cheese);
data.putExtras(check);
startActivityForResult(data, 5);
```

Should receive data in this activity (RecieveData Activity)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recievedata);
    Initializek();
    Bundle got = getIntent().getExtras();
    String ss= got.getString("UmerData");
    if(getIntent()!=null && ss!=null ) {
        rt1.setText("Is not Null");
    }
}
```

Your help will be really appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, startActivity & startActivityForResult, both take intent as param. You can bundle launch data inside intent and pass it over to target activity.

Comment: But I am unable to receive data in the called activity

Comment: In target activity, do getIntent() and then try to extract data from intent.

Comment: did that already. I first checked that getIntent() is not null than extracted the data using bundle data= getIntent().getExtras(); 
String cheese= data.getString(key);

Comment: You should be able to get data this way. can you post your source code both where you're setting the data and trying to extract it? What error are you seeing?

Comment: Can you post how you are adding extra in intent.

Comment: Any one ! Have I made any mistake in this code? Please notify me of that mistake

Answer (score 0):

When you use `startActivityForResult()`, you have to also create a `onActivityResult()` method within the Activity that called `startActivityForResult()`.  `onActivityResult()` is where you can access the Intent stored by the `Activity` you start for a result.

In the `Activity` that is then started, you have to call `setResult()` to store the `Intent` that you store the data in.

Read over this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

**edit:** Misread your question.  For passing a Bundle of options through, I would use this overload:

[`startActivity(Intent, int, Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: I made it clear that I am sending data from this SendData activity and then receiving it using onActivityResult. Just the data is not getting send using startActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in Xamarin Android so the code is C# but I had the same problem except I'm sending between separate apps. I eventually got it working so here is my example.

```
var intent = new Intent();
intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.company.packageName", "com.company.packageName.activityName"));
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, message);
StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

```
// in app being started
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    Intent intent = Intent; // Equivalent to getIntent()
    if (intent != null)
    {
           string str = intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);
           if (str != null)
           {
              // Do stuff with str
           }
           else
           {
               //Show Error
           }  
         }
     else
     {
              //Show Error
     }
}
```